# Python list of dictionaries: Get last item of each day

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries, ordered by the key `date`:

```
d = [{'date': datetime.strptime('2016-01-01 07:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), 'val': 1},
{'date': datetime.strptime('2016-01-01 23:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), 'val': 3},
{'date': datetime.strptime('2016-01-02 07:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), 'val': 5},
{'date': datetime.strptime('2016-01-02 22:13', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), 'val': 7},
{'date': datetime.strptime('2016-01-02 23:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), 'val': 9},
{'date': datetime.strptime('2016-01-03 00:10', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), 'val': 17},
{'date': datetime.strptime('2016-01-03 09:12', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), 'val': 25},
{'date': datetime.strptime('2016-01-03 21:52', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), 'val': 37}]
```

And i want to get the last(latest) item of each day, so in this case it would be:

```
{'date': datetime.strptime('2016-01-01 23:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), 'val': 3},
{'date': datetime.strptime('2016-01-02 23:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), 'val': 9},
{'date': datetime.strptime('2016-01-03 21:52', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), 'val': 37},
```

I have the following piece of code which does the trick:

```
previous_item = None
wanted_data = []
for index, entry in enumerate(d):
    if not previous_item:
        previous_item = entry
        continue
    if entry['date'].date() != previous_item['date'].date():
        wanted_data.append(previous_item)
    previous_item = entry

    #Add as well the last item
    if index + 1 == len(d):
        wanted_data.append(entry)
```

But i believe there are better and faster ways to do it... Besides, thats pretty ugly.

Is there a more pythonish way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a question for Code Review rather than Stack Overflow: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the data is already sorted by `'date'` (it seems to be in your case), you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group by the `date()`, and then get the last item from each group.

```
>>> d = sorted(d, key=lambda x: x["date"])  # only if not already sorted
>>> groups = itertools.groupby(d, lambda x: x["date"].date())
>>> wanted_data = [list(grp)[-1] for key, grp in groups]
>>> wanted_data
[{'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 23, 0), 'val': 3},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 23, 0), 'val': 9},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 3, 21, 52), 'val': 37}]
```

Note that this will expand each of the groups into a `list`. If this is too expensive, because there are very many entries for each date, you could create a function to get the last entry from an iterator, e.g. using `reduce` (or `functools.reduce` in Python 3):

```
>>> last = lambda x: functools.reduce(lambda x, y: y, x)
>>> wanted_data = [last(grp) for key, grp in groups]
```